# Creating 3D google chart from external json data to the html file

Tags: javascript, html, json, charts, google-visualization

I have a json file which has following content -

```
{"Passed":"1","Failed":"1","Other":"2","Inconclusive":"3"}
```

I want to create a html file which will render a pie chart with legend as passed (green), failed (red), inconclusive (pink or blue) and other (orange). When mouse is hovered over pie chart it should show the numbers as given in the json.

Here's the html code for 3D pie chart i created -

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Execution State', 'Number of tests'],
          ['Inconclusive',     3],
          ['Failed',      1],
          ['Other',  2],
          ['Passed', 1],
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Execution Result',
          is3D: true,
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="piechart_3d" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now i need the external json file to be supplied to my html file as data instead of passing the inline data to the html. How can i achieve this?
Any indicators to go about solving my issue will be much appreciated.
Thank You!

EDIT:
Here's the latest code which i'm using -

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Result</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martz90/circle/256/plex-icon.png"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"/>
        <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"/>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load("current", {
  packages:["corechart"]
}).then(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/TestExecutionResult.json",
    dataType: "json"
  }).done(function (jsonData) {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Execution State');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Number of tests');

    $.each(jsonData, function (key, value) {
      data.addRow([key, parseInt(value)]);
    });

    var options = {
      title: 'Execution Result',
      is3D: true,
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  });
});

        </script>
    </head>


    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th> Test result: </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="piechart_3d" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"/>

                </td>
            </table>
        </body>

    </html>
```

and the json (TestExecutionResult.json) which i've published on localhost -

```
{"TestCasesPassed":0,"TestCasesFailed":1,"TestCasesOther":0,"TestCasesInconclusive":0}
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Production Smoke Test Result</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martz90/circle/256/plex-icon.png"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"/>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load("current", {
  packages:["corechart"]
}).then(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/TestExecutionResult.json",
    dataType: "json"
  }).done(function (jsonData) {
    
    // send data to console
    console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonData));

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Execution State');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Number of tests');

    $.each(jsonData, function (key, value) {
      data.addRow([key, parseInt(value)]);
    });

    window.alert(jsonData);
    var options = {
      title: 'Execution Result',
      is3D: true,
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }).fail(function (jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {
    // add fail callback
    console.log('error: ' + errorThrown);
  });
});
        </script>
    </head>


    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th> Test result: </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="piechart_3d" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"/>

                </td>
            </table>
        </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jquery ajax to get the json data,
build the google data table,
and draw the chart.

see following snippet...

```
google.charts.load("current", {
  packages:["corechart"]
}).then(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: "path/data.json",
    dataType: "json"
  }).done(function (jsonData) {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Execution State');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Number of tests');

    $.each(jsonData, function (key, value) {
      data.addRow([key, parseInt(value)]);
    });

    var options = {
      title: 'Execution Result',
      is3D: true,
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  });
});
```

just be sure to include jquery on your page...

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

**EDIT**

try sending the data to the console to make sure it is being received as expected.
and, add the `fail` callback to see if the ajax call is receiving an error...

see following snippet...

```
google.charts.load("current", {
  packages:["corechart"]
}).then(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: "path/data.json",
    dataType: "json"
  }).done(function (jsonData) {
    
    // send data to console
    console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonData));

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Execution State');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Number of tests');

    $.each(jsonData, function (key, value) {
      data.addRow([key, parseInt(value)]);
    });

    var options = {
      title: 'Execution Result',
      is3D: true,
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }).fail(function (jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {
    // add fail callback
    console.log('error: ' + errorThrown);
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm getting this error message when i'm trying to access the json file located on my local computer -

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/TestExecutionResult.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.

Comment: does it need the json file to be accessed from http server? Coz this json file will be populated dynamically from an executable on my local hard drive which will serve as an input for google charts

Comment: I've tried your solution in multiple ways today, The above error doesn't come anymore but the html always displays a blank with just the table header which i've added in the body.
Here's the content of external json which i'm using -
{"TestCasesPassed":0,"TestCasesFailed":1,"TestCasesOther":0,"TestCasesInconclusive":0}.
The solution is same as what you've given me but it renders a blank html. I tried out other ways of making an AJAX call but it did not work for me :-(

Comment: json must be available from web server

Comment: I've placed it under apache htdocs. I'm able to access the json via web browser but still its rendering a blank html. no errors listed on console. Here's what i'm trying -
 $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/TestExecutionResult.json",
    dataType: "json"
  }).done(function (jsonData) {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Execution State');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Number of tests');

    $.each(jsonData, function (key, value) {
      data.addRow([key, parseInt(value)]);
    });

Comment: will you please edit the question with the latest code?

Comment: note: you can remove the old loader, it has been deprecated --> `https://www.google.com/jsapi`

Comment: It doesn't seem to work out. I'm still getting blank screen :-(

Comment: will you please share the result of the data sent to the console in the `done` callback, or the error message in the `fail` callback?

Comment: The console on microsoft-edge gives 1 warning - "Tracking prevention blocked access to storage for "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"

Google chrome shows 1 warning Indicate whether to send a cookie in cross-site request by specifying its samesite attribute

Apart from this the browser console shows nothing

Comment: The issue was with CORS. I added this statement  -- Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"  -- in my apache's httpd.conf and its working now. Thanks a million for your help with this. Really appreciate it.